# Insert test data in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode5, xctest

I'm currently writing some unit tests in a project using *Core Data* (Xcode 5). For testing purpose I need to insert a bundle of data into my *Core Data model* in the *setUp*.

What is the easiest way doing that? For instance it would be helpful if I could write an XML file and populate this into my *Core Data*.

Comment: You can use [Valentina studio](http://www.valentina-db.com/de/all-downloads) to open Core Data Model(SQLite file) and insert values.

Comment: I would like it to be inserted automatically.

Comment: I'm yet to find a simple way. I have followed this see chap 7, http://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/Core-Data-iOS-OS-X/101461-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a1%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3acore+data%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2

Comment: Could you not make a copy of the database from the Application Sandbox and seed it at launch time for your Unit Tests?

Comment: You can use mockup Core Data file with values. When test it You will use context with this Database.

Comment: Using this tool is not a bad idea, otherwise you will have to write a lot of code to mock the data.

Comment: Does Valentina understand the Core Data model, or does it just edit the SQLite file?

Comment: What You mean by understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up inserting the test data programatically in the test setup.